# Clase y constructores

Tags: javascript, clase, constructor

Llevo toda la mañana intentando descifrar este enunciado y no soy capaz:

*Crea un archivo "coche.js" que implemente una clase Coche con un constructor con las siguientes características:

- Debe recibir 3 parámetros: peso, potencia y marca.
- Peso y potencia deben ser números, y marca una String.
- La clase debe tener variables de clase en las que se almacene el valor de los parámetros pasados al constructor.
  La clase Coche debe ser exportada como un módulo para poder ser usada desde otros archivos javascript.*

Yo creo que se debe hacer así:

```
class Coche = {
 peso: 1500,
  potencia: 150,
  marca: "Seat"
}
```

Pero cuando dice: La clase debe tener variables de clase en las que se almacene el valor de los parámetros pasados al constructor, pues esto ya me descoloca...

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto?

Comment: ¿Has buscado "clase con constructor javascript" en google?  Con la primera coincidencia aclararás esas dudas

Answer (score -2):

Con esa sintaxis estas definiendo algo que puede ser un namespace si cambias la palabra reservada 'class' por 'var', 'let' o 'const' (un namespace es algo así como un objeto), para definir clases con sus propiedades debes usar esta sintaxis:

```js
class Carro{
    constructor(){
        this.peso = 1500;
        this.potencia = 150;
        this.marca = 'seat';
    }
}
```

Luego puedes instanciar la clase para acceder a sus propiedades:

```js
carro = new Carro();
console.log(carro.potencia);
```

Comment: Revisa bien el contenido de la pregunta y actualiza tu respuesta. Tu clase no está recibiendo parámetros en el constructor y es una de las cosas que le piden, y tampoco le aclaras lo que son las variables de clase que no entiende.

Comment: @masterguru ¿Entonces cómo debería hacerlo? Estoy encallado en este ejercicio y no encuentro la solución

Comment: @Vistur ¿te has mirado y leído el enlace de mi primer comentario a tu pregunta?    Empieza por allí, y si te surgen dudas las comentamos, pero pon de tu parte primero, pues allí lo explica la mar de bien. Esa búsqueda que te propuse deberia haberte devuelto este [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)  donde se explican las clases y todo lo que necesitas saber.  Si te lo tengo que contar yo paso a paso va a ser exactamente lo mismo, así que mejor lo lees de allí y ganamos tiempo todos, gracias.

Comment: Como truco adicional, puedes usar https://jsfiddle.net/ para realizar pruebas de tu código de forma facil, rellenando la casilla del javascript con tu definición de clase, y depurando con console.log() todo lo que necesites saber. Luego ejecutas el codigo pulsando RUN y abre la consola integrada pulsando sobre "Console (Beta)" al pie del recuadro en blanco.  Si aprendes a utilizar esa herramienta y depurar tu código con console.log() te librarás de muchas preguntas aquí y no iras tan perdido.

Comment: @masterguru Al final he podido sacar el código, pero de la segunda parte soy incapaz:


Modifica el archivo del ejercicio anterior para que los atributos sean privados y tengan sus correspondientes getters y setters.

Comment: @Vistur me alegro por ti, ya ves que no era tan dificil, pero eso de los getters y setters no está en la pregunta. Básicamente un getter no es más que una función de la clase, por ejemplo, getPeso(), donde le haces un return de una propiedad, ya sea privada o publica, con un `return this->peso` por ejemplo.  Y un setter pues similar, seria una funcion llamada setPeso(valor) donde le asignas un valor a la propiedad mediante `this->peso = valor` dentro de la función.  Lo de private lo veras [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Comment: @masterguru 

Creo tener algo adelantado:


class Coche{ 
  #peso = 0; // Variables privadas
  #potencia = 0;
  #marca = '';

  function getpeso(){
    return this.#peso;
  }

  function setPeso(nuevoPeso){
    this.#peso = nuevoPeso;
  }
  
  ...

}
Con el simbolo '#' hacemos los atributos privados

Simplemente faltan los metodos getter y setter para poder obtener o modificar dichos atributos, pero no se como tengo que hacerlo...

Comment: @Vistur Diria que ya lo tienes, tan solo deja el constructor como estaba (cambiando las variables por las privadas), luego create un coche fuera de la clase así:  `nuevoCoche = new Coche(parametros con valores)` y luego consulta el peso mediante `console.log(nuevoCoche.getpeso())`, luego se lo cambias con `nuevoCoche.setPeso(nuevo_valor)`, y finalmente se lo vuelves a consultar a ver si lo ha hecho con lo mismo: `console.log(nuevoCoche.getpeso())` y yasta (bueno, no se si quieren getters y setters para todas las propiedades o solo la del peso)

Comment: @Vistur y de paso mirate este enlace para entenderlo mejor: https://yeisondaza.com/entendiendo-getters-y-setters-en-javascript